# R: tell if a substring exists in another string

Tags: r

I am looking for a function (let's call it `scramblematch`) that can do the following.

```
query='one five six'
target1='one six two six three four five '
target2=' two five six'
```

`scramblematch(query, target1)` returns `TRUE` and

`scramblematch(query, targ2)` returns `FALSE`

The `stringdist` package might be what I need, but I don't know how to use it.

**Update1**

Use case for the function I am looking for: I have a dataset with data entered gradually over the years. Values for one text field (`textfield`) of the dataset is not standardized so people entered differently. Now I want to clean up this data by using a standardized set of values for `textfield`. All those values that describes the same things by different wordings are to be replaced by standardized values. For example (I am making this up):

In my standardized choices of values (let's call this `lookupfactors`), I have `lookupfactors=c('liver disease', 'and more')`.
In the `textfield` I have following rows:

```
liver cancer disease
some other thing
male, liver fibrosis disease
yet another thing
failure of liver, disease
```

I want in the final result, to have row 1, 3, and 5 (because they have 'liver' and 'disease' in the content) to be replaced by `liver disease`. Here I assume that people who entered the data do not know the precise term, but they know the keywords to put it. Therefore words in the values of `lookupfactors` are substring/subset of those in `textfield`.

Comment: Do you want to check whether each word in `query` appears in the target string? If so, you can try `Reduce("&",lapply(strsplit(query," ")[[1]],grepl,c(target1,target2)))`.

Comment: Very good demonstration of `Reduce`. Using `Reduce` like so is what I need: `Reduce("&",lapply(strsplit(query," ")[[1]],grepl,target1))` and `Reduce("&",lapply(strsplit(query," ")[[1]],grepl,target2))`. Thank you. But I wonder if there is any other faster method.

Comment: You don't need separate calls, if you need speed. Just create a vector of target strings and use my line. It should be fast enough, I guess.

Comment: You found this method to be slow?

Comment: I haven't done benchmarking. `Reduce` is not slow. It is just my intuition when looking at the usage of `lapply` and `grepl`. The set query with `%in%` in the answer by docendo below may be faster.

Comment: @biocyberman There's a subtle difference between using `grepl` and `%in%`. Can you please specify what you need for your real data?

Comment: @docendodiscimus please check out **Update1** in my question.

Answer (score 3):

One option to implement it is with `%in%` and `strsplit`:

```
scramblematch <- function(query, target, sep = " ") {
  all(unlist(strsplit(query, sep)) %in% unlist(strsplit(target, sep)))
}
scramblematch(query, target1)
#[1] TRUE
scramblematch(query, target2)
#[1] FALSE
```

---

A vectorized approach using `stringi` could be

```
library(stringi)
scramblematch <- function(query, target, sep = " ") {
  q <- stri_split_fixed(query, sep)[[1L]]
  sapply(stri_split_fixed(target, sep), function(x) {
    all(q %in% x)
  })
}

scramblematch(query, c(target1, target2))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Maybe also (similarly) `library(stringi) ; all(stri_detect_fixed(target1, stri_split_fixed(query, " ")[[1]]))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, yep, I thought so too.

Answer (score 3):

You can try (the `fixed=TRUE` improvement is from @David's comment):

```
scramblematch<-function(query,target) {
   Reduce("&",lapply(strsplit(query," ")[[1]],grepl,target,fixed=TRUE))
}
```

Some benchmark:

```
query='one five six'
target1='one six two six three four five '
target2=' two five six'
target<-rep(c(target1,target2),10000)
system.time(scramblematch(query,target))   
# user  system elapsed 
#0.008   0.000   0.008
scramblematchDD <- function(query, target, sep = " ") {
  all(unlist(strsplit(query, sep)) %in% unlist(strsplit(target, sep)))
}
system.time(vapply(target,scramblematchDD,query=query,TRUE))   
# user  system elapsed 
#0.657   0.000   0.658
```

The `vapply` in the @docendodiscimus solution is needed, since it is not vectorized.

Comment: Maybe add `fixed = TRUE` for some additional speed gain.

Comment: My answer is not vectorized because they didn't ask for such implementation in the question. Of course it would not make sense to strsplit the query each time if speed is a concern.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Tx, that speeds up things by a factor of 3.

Comment: Wow big difference. I was wrong about the speed of this approach.